# What are those "sticks" on Jyn Erso's back?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one, object-identification

After my wife and I first viewed Rogue One we both walked away and mutually we had one question hanging around.  What are these two stick/sword things hanging from Jyn's back?

[image]

To my recollection, she never uses them in the film so as a prop-piece it seemed like an odd thing to have put on a costume.  This made my wife and I speculate that something must have been cut from the film that would have explained their purpose.

Further details that might be spoilers:

> I am aware that she's wearing this outfit because she and the other rebels have taken out a few Imperial troopers and that they are wearing their uniforms as disguise.  She *appears* to be wearing a gunner's uniform, though I'm not 100% sure that is what the outfit is.  I assume this could be part of the uniform.  Regardless, I see no example of a gunner wearing these devices, so I'm not sure that she is, in fact, wearing a gunner's outfit.

My main problem is that I've never seen these devices before, nor do I recall seeing their use in the movie.

So... what are they?

Comment: The real-world term for this job is "Aircraft marshaller". You can see a marshaller using the batons to direct SW-0608 as it lands on Scarif, as well as the slots on his back for storing them when not in use.

Comment: recall the uniforms of the two that were jumped...

Comment: Thanks @naib!  However, only after one viewing I couldn't quite recall.  I enjoyed the film considerably but I couldn't remember every little detail.

Comment: @RLH true. The only reason I posted the comment was I thought the same thing at the time but then immediately recalled where the uniforms came from

Comment: @naib, no problem and no complaints!  Obviously, when this is out on Blu-Ray in 7-8 months, and others have viewed this film 1000x, this will seem like a silly question... just trying to hold onto any street cred that I may still have. ;)

Comment: The real problem is that an imperial officer, some stormtroopers, and the flight control guy all go into a ship, right in front of another officer. Yet a totally different imperial officer, no storm troopers, and a robot get out, the flight control guy takes a break, and no one says anything.....:P

Comment: That image was not actually in the movie

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The [Rogue One: The Ultimate Visual Guide](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Rogue-Ultimate-Visual-x/dp/146545263X) factbook describes them as

> **ILLUMINATED TRAFFIC WANDS**
>
> [image]

They were part of the outfit that Jyn stole from Imperial "Deck Technician" [Kent Deezling](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kent_Deezling). You can see him using them to signal landing ships in the clip below.

[image]

Comment: And, there you go.  Thanks.

Comment: "Kent"? What kind of name is that in the galaxy far, far away?

Comment: @Terriblefan You mean, almost as down-to-Earth a name as "Luke"?

Comment: @MrLister Touché.

Comment: Man, that's disappointing...  I was really hoping she was going to use them to beat down some stormtroopers, too :(

Comment: @Taegost - Have a look at the HISHE review of Rogue One. Who knows, maybe in the original cut she did :-)

Comment: Yeah this is definitely right but epically underwhelming

Comment: @Taegost They cut the climactic scene where she puts the mask back on and guides incoming Empire reinforcements into a lake.

Comment: @GGMG - That would be awesome...  "No, don't worry, it's a Force Mirage, there really is solid ground underneath...  Really, you can trust me, I've got the wands!"

Comment: @Terriblefan Ah, with a name like Kent Deezling I tend to concoct my own story for the guy...  He always had a little sympathy for the rebels but the Empire had stationed he and his family on that "perfect" beach-resort of a planet that had the boring purpose of keeping archives.  The Empire gave him the easy job of guiding in cargo ships to the archives facility.  Yup... nothing could be more perfect or could ever go wrong here for such a simple guy, with a simple name and a simple job.  It's paradise!

Comment: @RLH - he's a pilot. Maybe he escaped somehow.

Comment: @Valorum, one can hope.  But being that our main character is wearing his clothes, theres a good chance he's dead. :`(  RIP, Kent Deezling. RIP.

Comment: @RLH No, don't worry, he's just tied up in a utility closet in the hangar, wearing only his boxers and an undershirt. He spent the first hour or so yelling for help, but it's so noisy that no-one could hear. He's not worried, though, because the night shift should be in in a few hours, and they'll find him, and then, man, what a story he'll have to tell at parties.

Comment: @Inquisitiveidiot - Sorry.

Comment: This is at once a great answer and the most disappointing I have ever read... I was hoping she was some kind of Samurai. Turns out she's a *traffic warden*.

Comment: @Wikis: Worse... she's _pretending_ to be a traffic warden.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I am reminded of the joke that asks for the reason "why traffic wardens have a red band on their hats", the answer being "to prevent people from parking there"

Comment: Note: The bonus material for DVD shows (but doesn't mention or explain) unused footage of Jyn using at least one of the batons as a weapon in the Imperial archive or whatever on the tropical beach planet.

Answer (score 68):

It looks like the wands used by the air marshaller to direct the cargo shuttles when they were landing.  You can see the red sections at the tips of the rods that light up and help indicate to the pilot what they need to do and where to move.  Similar to what you see in a real life airport.

Lego version since I can't seem to find the movie version (Valorum has the better movie version, so I'm keeping the Lego one):
[image]

Comment: Ah, good call and quite plausible.  I'm going to leave this one open hoping someone can find a better image, or technical reference, though.

Comment: @RLH Understandable.  Even searching for "Scarif Landing crew" you find this and the action figures. No stills from the movie.

Comment: The term for this job (in our world) is "Aircraft marshaller". You see someone using the wands as shuttle SW-0608 is coming in to land on Scarif, as well as the slots on his back for holding the wands when not in use.

Comment: @Werrf Not to be confused with the Air Marshall?   I couldn't remember the exact terms form the landing crew.

Answer (score 12):

They are from the Aircraft Marshaller they take the suit from. As everyone else mentions they are for guiding the ships to the landing pad. As to answer your question as to the now you see it and now you don't. She took them off. If you recall the scene where they were trying to retrieve the hard drive and the machine jammed, Jyn got the idea of having to blast the glass to go get it manually and you can see her taking off her suit in order to be lighter to make the jump, the sticks are the first things she takes off. I hope that helps.

Comment: I recall the scene but completely missed that.  I guess my mind was having a tough time keeping up with all of those secondary-details.  Thanks and welcome to SciFi.SE.